# What is the difference between Github Packages and Npm Private packages?

Tags: github, npm, npm-package, github-package-registry, github-packages

We want to publish private packages within our company. But I can't understand the difference between Github packages and NPM private packages. For me both seems like registry for hosting private packages. But what are the differences and  Which should I choose and based on what?